# does this very simple relationship make sense?

Tags: foreign-key-relationship

So I am just wondering what it means for a foreign key relationship. I have two tables. Courses and Schools. One school can have many courses. So does the following relationship make sense?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Relation looks fair. The courses are linked to a school. It might cause issues if you want to have a course that is teached at multiple schools. In that case you should add a "link" table between them. That table would contain couse and school id's (telling what items are linked to eachother).

Only one negative thing I can think about in your example is the naming of you tables, all tables are prefixed with proj_ while the columns are prefilled with the name of the table (and for Foreign keys the name of the linked table too). The link course_schoolId links to the table proj_school, this might cause confusion in larger datamodels.